# Java decompiling to Eclipse then recompiling

Tags: java, eclipse

I have used jdGUI to decompile a jar file (with permission), and now I am left with a zip file. How would I move this zip into Eclipse for editing and re-compiling?

I tried but I am getting lots of errors. Will I need to import any Google things? I have a Google folder in there too.

EDIT I have extracted the zip in to my projects folder, but I cant figure out how to access it from Eclipse.

Comment: 1. do you know how to unzip a file? If you are on Windows, you can download 7zip  2. do you know Java?  3. do you know how to create a project in Eclipse?  If you answer "no" to (2) and (3), I think you should seek out a very basic introduction to both.

Comment: I suspect you're in over your head.  Decompiled Java is going to be very ugly.

Comment: If you have permission to decompile, why not ask the author for the source code?  Is your goal to learn to use jdGUI or work on the code in question?

Comment: One doesn't decompile a jar file. Just as one doesn't drive to the shops on their pencil.  A jar file is like a zip file, a compressed file. You decompile class files

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer as it's a bit long for a comment.

There are two different issues. Two different questions.

1)compiling it

2)running it in eclipse.

For compiling it, state the error. Compile it from the command prompt. If you can't do that then you should not be using a GUI.

For running it in Eclipse, state the method you are using, and the error.

Try giving JD-GUI a class file rather than a jar file. The site for JD-GUI says http://jd.benow.ca/   JD-GUI is a standalone graphical utility that displays Java source codes of “.class” files.

I'd think you'd want to unjar the jar file, i.e. decompress it Then when you have class files, if you want source code, try JD-GUI.

It's very bad that you haven't stated the method you used and the errors you got. And that you haven't broken down the problem into its constituent parts